# Joomla 3 Hide a position on certain pages

Tags: css, joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I have a custom template that I am using in my website. To the right of my pages I have a position with a background color that I do not want to display on my terms of use page. The position contains a twitter module which I can remove from the page but I am still left with a small box containing the background color from the css. Can I completely remove this position from just the terms of use page.

Comment: Yes, where is your page at?

Comment: for example http://www.alanmccarthy.com/ this is the home page and here is the terms page http://www.alanmccarthy.com/terms-of-use as you can see the grey box still appears even though it contains nothing

Comment: Can you modify your HTML?

Comment: yes i can modify the html

Comment: So the problem is the background color is associated with the position right? I would say why don't you count have many modules will be displayed and then condition the background class based on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Terms of use page, add a custom class say `terms-of-use` and then override it with `background: transparent`

The dynamic custom class can be generated through [**Adding custom class on Joomla pages**](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/5398/adding-custom-css-styling-on-some-of-my-pages)

**CSS**

```
body.terms-of-use .social {
  background: transparent;
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: but this then hides the background on the other pages, for example now it does not display on the home page

Comment: Try this: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/5398/adding-custom-css-styling-on-some-of-my-pages and check the browser for the generated page id for Terms of use page.

Comment: that seems like it should be working  is the correct syntax for the css .pageid113.social{   } or do I need to be more specific with the name

Comment: I have updated my code. `.pageid11.social` will not work since it is a multiple class selector. Currently your pages generated dynamic classes with a name. So use `.terms-of-use`

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the html template, look for the place where the module is shown in the index.php will be like this ...

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="social" style="none" />
```

And add some code in PHP, so that only the module is displayed, when the module is published. In this way joomla will not write anything if there is no content to show and will not need to do anything in the CSS, besides improving the loading of the page.

```
<?php if($this->countModules('social')) : ?>
     <jdoc:include type="modules" name="social" style="none" />
<?php endif; ?>
```